# flask url_for returns internal server error

Tags: python, flask

I am tryin to have a form submit to a python script using flask. the form is in my index.html -

```
<form action="{{ url_for('/predict') }}" method="POST">
    <p>Enter Mileage</p>
    <input type="text" name="mileage">
    <p>Enter Year</p>
    <input type="text" name="year">
    <input type="submit" value="Predict">
</form>
```

Here is my flask page (my_flask.py)-

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def predict():
    df = pd.read_csv("carprices.csv")
    X = df[['Mileage','Year']]
    y = df['Sell Price($)']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

if request.method == 'POST':
    mileage = request.form['mileage']
    year = request.form['year']
    data = [[mileage, year]]
    price = clf.predict(data)
return render_template('prediction.html', prediction = price)
```

But when I go to my index page I get internal server error because of the

Why would this be happening?
    {{ url_for('/predict') }}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `url_for('/predict')`, drop the leading slash and use `url_for('predict')`.

`url_for(...)` takes the method name and not the route name.

Comment: Thank you, yes this was another issue I had, I also needed to import url_for

Comment: I do run into another issue now, which is I get the 404 not found when the form is submitted.. Somehow my path is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I was not importing url_for.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for
```

Comment: If that were the case, then the code would not have compiled.

Comment: Yeah not sure, I'm using pythonanywhere.. it works now